# What is the better way to pass the parameter with xml tags via web service url in iOS, objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xml, web-services

I'm working with a web service to get value. I'm passing values through the web service url.there is a parameter that include `xml` tags.I put that string as following image.

[image]

then I add the values to the `url` like following.

```
NSString *checkingbaseUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myson.ascentur.au/AUMobile.asmx/FlightBooking?Authkey=%@&Reqxml=%@&infovia=%@&totalpax=%@&totalfare=%@&flightsegmentcount=%@&from=%@&destination=%@&departuredate=%@&returndate=%@&airlinecode=%@&cabinclass=%@&cabinclasses=%@",authkey,requestXml,infovia, totalPax, totalfare,flightsegmentcount,from,destination,departuredate,returndate,airline,cabinclass,cabinClassess];
```

but the response is an `error`.
when I see in the browser it shows this error :

```
A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (Reqxml=&quot;&lt;BPC9&gt; &lt;MSG_VERSION&gt;...&quot;).
```

in my app,it returns an error with follow

```
Request failed: not found (404)
```

this is how I request `via` AFNetworking

```
   NSString *checkingbaseUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myson.ascentur.au/AUMobile.asmx/FlightBooking?Authkey=%@&Reqxml=%@&infovia=%@&totalpax=%@&totalfare=%@&flightsegmentcount=%@&from=%@&destination=%@&departuredate=%@&returndate=%@&airlinecode=%@&cabinclass=%@&cabinclasses=%@",authkey,requestXml,infovia,totalPax,totalfare,flightsegmentcount,from,destination,departuredate,returndate,airline,cabinclass,cabinClassess];

    NSString *basedUrl = [checkingbaseUrl stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *bookingmanager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [bookingmanager GET:checkingbaseUrl parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject)
    {
        NSString *responseS = (NSString *)responseObject;
        NSLog(@"resoponseS : %@", responseS);


    }
    failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"anurdh_caldera :%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
```

I want to know, is this the correct way to pass `requestXml` parameter (I have no idea how to add this string with these type of special characters).

hope your help with this.

Comment: Is it a POST method? If YES, shouldn't you put it into the HTTPBody ? What object are you using for the request?

Comment: no this is `GET` method ,and I'm using `AFNetworking` to communicate with the web service

Answer (score 0):

Check after replacing brackets using below method:

```
requestXml=[self replaceSpecialCharsFromString:requestXml];

-(NSString*)replaceSpecialCharsFromString:(NSString*)str
{
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@"&lt;"];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@"&gt;"];
    return str;
}
```

Comment: in my url cannot be white space.but there is `%` tags in most places

Comment: I updated the question. I tried your answer.but didn't get successful result